# Unreachable command line option in MAIN

Tags: syntax, raku

[zef search](https://github.com/ugexe/zef/blob/a606f316324187775fe49ea21ad6881dce4751f6/lib/Zef/CLI.pm6#L217) includes `:$update` as a named argument:

```
 multi MAIN('search', Int :$wrap = False, :$update, *@terms ($, *@))
```

However, it's not recognized as such:

```
% zef search --update
Usage:
  /home/jmerelo/.rakudobrew/bin/../moar-2019.03.1/install/share/perl6/site/bin/zef [--wrap=<Int>] search [<terms> ...] -- Get a list of possible distribution candidates for the given terms
  /home/jmerelo/.rakudobrew/bin/../moar-2019.03.1/install/share/perl6/site/bin/zef [--version] -- Detailed version information
  /home/jmerelo/.rakudobrew/bin/../moar-2019.03.1/install/share/perl6/site/bin/zef [-h|--help]
```

What am I missing here? How could I assign a value to this `$update`?

Comment: The line in question was added 10 days ago and looks to be in the most recent 0.7.3 version. Are you running that version?

Comment: @scimon that's a good one. Could really be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I run this `MAIN` candidate by itself, it works:

```
$ perl6 -e 'multi MAIN("search", Int :$wrap = False, :$update, *@terms ($, *@)) { say "foo" }' search --update
foo
```

so it looks to me there is more than one candidate that matches, and that causes the USAGE feedback message to appear.

Named parameters are used as tie-breakers only, unless they are made mandatory (which makes them effectively a part of the dispatch process).  So maybe the fix is to make two candidates:

```
multi MAIN('search', Int :$wrap = False, :$update!, *@terms ($, *@)) { ... }
multi MAIN('search', Int :$wrap = False,            *@terms ($, *@)) { ... }
```

?

Comment: This implies that that particular piece of code is mainly part of an internal API for zef, rather than for user interaction, right? I wonder also how is it possible that :$update is hidden from the usage message, while :$wrap, which is not compulsory, is not.

Comment: Perhaps creating an issue for this is in order, once golfed  :-)